# First list view is populating but on clicking particular field this comes java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, json, listview, android-emulator

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

            new DownloadJSON().execute();
            /*
            Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
            btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");


            listview.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

    btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DownloadJSON().execute();
        }
    });*/

        }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://hackerearth.0x10.info/api/payment_portals?type=json&query=list_gateway");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("payment_gateways");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    map.put("description", jsonobject.getString("description"));
                    map.put("branding", jsonobject.getString("branding"));
                    map.put("rating", jsonobject.getString("rating"));
                    map.put("currencies", jsonobject.getString("currencies"));
                    map.put("setup_fee", jsonobject.getString("setup_fee"));

                    map.put("transaction_fees", jsonobject.getString("transaction_fees"));
                    map.put("how_to_document", jsonobject.getString("how_to_document"));

                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    TextView name;
    Intent intent;

    ImageView imageView;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables


        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

        resultp = data.get(position);

        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textName);

        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        name.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.NAME));

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.IMAGE), imageView);
        // Capture ListView item click

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                resultp = data.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", resultp.get(MainActivity.NAME));
                //intent.putExtra("image", resultp.get(MainActivity.IMAGE));
                //intent.putExtra("transaction_fees",resultp.get(MainActivity.TRANSACTION_FEES));
                //intent.putExtra("setup_fee", resultp.get(MainActivity.SETUP_FEE));
                //intent.putExtra("rating", resultp.get(MainActivity.RATING));
                //intent.putExtra("description", resultp.get(MainActivity.DESCRIPTION));
                //intent.putExtra("branding",resultp.get(MainActivity.BRANDING));


                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



        return itemView;
    }
}
```

SingleItemView.java

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
    // Declare Variables
    String name, image, transaction_fees,setup_fee, how_to_document,branding,rating, description;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);
    Intent i;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);

         i = getIntent();

        name = i.getStringExtra("name");
        //image = i.getStringExtra("image");
        //transaction_fees = i.getStringExtra("transaction_fees");
        //setup_fee = i.getStringExtra("setup_fee");
        //how_to_document = i.getStringExtra("how_to_document");
        //branding = i.getStringExtra("branding");
        //rating = i.getStringExtra("rating");
        //description= i.getStringExtra("description");



        TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        //TextView txtTransaction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTransaction);
        //TextView txtSetup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textSetup);
        //TextView txtBranding = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textBranding);
        //RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        //TextView txtDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDescription);


        //ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePayment);

        //ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(rating));
        txtName.setText(name);
        //txtTransaction.setText(transaction_fees);
        //txtSetup.setText(setup_fee);
        //txtBranding.setText(branding);
        //txtDescription.setText(description);
        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(image, imgView);
    }
```

LogCat

```
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.PaymentGateway/com.example.PaymentGateway.SingleItemView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getCacheDir(ContextWrapper.java:188)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.example.PaymentGateway.FileCache.<init>(FileCache.java:18)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.example.PaymentGateway.ImageLoader.<init>(ImageLoader.java:34)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.example.PaymentGateway.SingleItemView.<init>(SingleItemView.java:13)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-14 11:57:46.537: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

Comment: initialize your intent in adapter

Comment: post your whole sigleitem activity

Comment: from log i can tell you that error is at line number 13 in SingleItemView calss check that line what is it?

Comment: ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this); this is call to my other class. i got it. error is in this line only. thanks.